# How many times does ConstraintLayout measure each of its children?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

RelativeLayout measures all its children twice. This can cause performance issues. Does constraint layout only measure its children once each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` requires up to two measure passes.

If you look at the `ConstraintLayout`'s source, you'll see that its `onMeasure()` method first measures its children inside an `internalMeasureChildren()` utility method. Next, it evaluates some constraints. Finally, `ConstraintLayout` calls `child.measure()` on its children a second time inside a loop.

Source: decompiled the class files, since the source isn't available at this time.

Comment: Where can I get these sources from?

Comment: It does not measure twice every time. It only needs to measure twice for children whose width can change (because it could affect the height).

Comment: @Zielony, I decompiled the class file since the source isn't available yet.